# Error from Tomcat 7 to 8.5 Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class

Tags: java, tomcat8.5, slackware

I've changed the runtime server environment of my application from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8.5. It loads fine in my development environment in Eclipse IDE, but I get some `myfaces` related errors in the production environment, which is Linux Slackware 14.2.

Exception in **`catalina.out`** file:

```
29-Jun-2020 02:47:31.039 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces An error occured while initializing MyFaces: null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:1058)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1863)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.getFacesConfig(DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:309)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.getFacesConfig(DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:36)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getStandardFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:135)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.getFacesConfigData(DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.java:69)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:416)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:355)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:142)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Exception in **`localhost.log`** file:

```
30-Jun-2020 02:13:07.103 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:206)
        at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getApplication(FacesContextImplBase.java:159)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._dispatchApplicationEvent(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:280)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.destroyFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:315)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(StartupServletContextListener.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4735)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
30-Jun-2020 02:13:07.104 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
30-Jun-2020 02:13:07.104 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:988)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:556)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4735)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can anybody help with figuring out what exactly is preventing this from loading? I can post other configuration files as well.

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you have any jars in your old tomcat's `lib` folder? You might need to copy them across to the new installation.

Comment: Yep, it's all there. The libs in both the tomcat directory and in the respective web app folder as well.